# How to acces an image/file in blazor @code section

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0

Looking into opening an image on a blazor page's @code section, but I keep getting the following error.

`System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\img\Account\Pamphlet Design.png'`

Here is the code that I have tried among other:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Environment.ContentRootPath, @"/img/Account/Pamphlet Design.png");

var plampletBitmap = new Bitmap(path); // Error Here
```

Comment: Are you using Blazor Server? Your code uses an *absolute* path too - whatever `ContentRootPath` contains, you'd end up with a `path` that starts at the disk's root.  At the very least use `"img/Account/Pamphlet Design.png"`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that does not work as ContentRootPath does not return the full required path. However, I found `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` does return the correct path, and I was able to load it through that. I will test the path without the `/img` now.

Comment: What will you then do with this image you have loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that Blazor can access an ASP.NET content root path, maybe in server mode, almost certainly not in web assembly mode.

Normally to access images you can create a /images folder under the Blazor Client's wwwroot and load the images from there via: images/filename. I just compute the path in the model and bind it directly to an `<img src="@Model.ImagePath">`

For Blazor server you could try `Path.Combine(Environment.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot", "img/Account", "Pamphlet Design.png");` I think even in Blazor server it sandboxes file access, though the leading slash in "/img" might also just be the problem if not.

Comment: Image loading in the view is fine. The reason I want the image from the server is that I am generating a QR code on the fly. I then use a Template image from the server and superimpose the QR code on the image. That allows me to create custom pamphlets for the user on the fly with their store code on int.

Comment: @MrMoonMan for starters, you're probably using Blazor Server. You wouldn't be able to even access `C:` from a browser. Second, you used an absolute path. Remove the leading `/`

Comment: Could try `Path.Combine(Environment.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot", "img/Account", "Pamphlet Design.png");` I think even in Blazor server it sandboxes file access, though the leading slash in "/img" might also just be the problem if not.

Comment: @StevePy that worked perfectly post an answer and I will accept that.

Comment: I've added the blazor server comment to this answer. Good to hear you're up and running. I've just recently started with Blazor and absolutely loving it so far. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have file in wwwroot folder of your project "wwwroot\img\Account\Pamphlet Design.png"

In your razor page, Inject WebHostEnvironment in your razor page

```
@inject IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment;
```

Get your file path like this

```
string path = hostEnvironment.WebRootPath + @"\img\Account\Pamphlet Design.png";
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a "Image" folder in "wwwroot"

copy "myimage.jpg" in to the "Image" folder

```html
< img src="../Image/myimage.jpg" alt="myimage..." >
```

it works

Comment: The question was how to reference the file in the @code section, not the template section.